# bluetooth pairing microsoft ergonomic keyboard

Tags: bluetooth

I've managed to pair a microsoft bluetooth mouse without a passkey. When pairing the keyboard a popup with a passkey appears and I've tried entering it into the keyboard as well as the laptop but it always fails.

I'm using a system76 laptop that has elementaryOS installed. I've also installed the system-76 drivers.

[image]